# Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Profiler' not found in /app/Mage.php

Tags: php, magento-enterprise, profiler

So this is an odd one. I am running Magento EE 1.14.2.1 with php 5.5.34 with Zend OPcache.

I installed [AOE Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) and fixed a few issues and now I wanted to uninstall. So I removed all files, however, I keep receiving this error about Varien profiler:

> Warning: include(/app/code/community/Varien/Profiler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   Warning: include(/app/code/community/Varien/Profiler.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Profiler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Profiler' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 665

Magento is supposed to start looking in lib/Varien/Profiler.php which exists, but it doesn't.

I also ran the following to try and fix this:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush(); 
opcache_reset();
```

Also download n98-magerun.phar and ran:

```
php n98-magerun.phar cache:clean
php n98-magerun.phar cache:flush
php n98-magerun.phar cache:dir:flush
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/full_page_cache
```

With it still giving the above error. Now here is the odd thing. When i refresh the page, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: Same thing for me, probably because of Redis used (even all caches is disabled). I have to move varien and zend folder withing community folder of AOE Profiler back. I also flushed all caches. Sad the thread is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I contacted Rackspace, and I believe the issue ended up being that the user that runs PHP didn't have permission to run `opcache_reset();`

Logging in as root and restarting Apache worked

```
service httpd restart
```